# Ronchi Rules or graduated and varied strokes in illustrator or Inkscape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, inkscape

I am searching for an easy way to create (in vector) something like this:

[image]

essentially I would like to create lines starting for example: black 5pt, white 5pt, black 4pt, white 4pt, etc... all the way down to .001pt WITHOUT having to create each line individually.

any ideas or easy ways to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried Blends? What have you tried?

Comment: no i have not tried blends.. I have tried transform and distort, zizag... (transform>effects) 

ok let me give it a try

thanks

f

Answer (score 1):

As SVGs are XML-based, it’s relatively simple to write yourself a program that generates the lines as desired. Just generate yourself a file with two lines and take a look at the source to learn the relevant parts of the syntax.

If you lack the programming skills and if you want the line thicknesses to decay exponentially, you can do the following (described for Inkscape):

1. Create two 5 pt lines, (shown in long/black and short/red, below).
2. Open the *Align and Distribute* tab and set *Relative to* to *First selected.*
3. Select the longer line and then the shorter one.
4. Use *Align left edges of objects to the right edge of the anchor.*

   [image]
5. Group the lines.
6. Open the *Create Tiled Clones* dialogue and *Reset* if you have used it before.
7. Go to the *Scale Tab* and use settings like these (0.8 is the factor by which each line is smaller than the one to its left):

   [image]
8. Create your Clones.

   [image]
9. Remove the Clone positioned on your initial object.
10. Select all your Clones (beware that some of them may be nearly invisible).
11. Use *Align Right Side* (alignment tab)
12. Use *Remove Overlaps* with the *H* and *V* set to 0 (also alignment tab)

    [image]
13. Select the short line in your original (holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>).
14. Remove it.

    [image]